# The cookie-based redirect on my WordPress site is not functioning properly

Tags: wordpress, redirect, cookies, setcookie, template-redirect

I'm attempting to create a cookie-based redirect that sets a cookie for a duration of one hour and redirects the user to a different page. However, within that hour, this redirection cannot be triggered. In this example, I have excluded the PHP code used to retrieve the country code.

```
<?php
// COUNTRY CODE RE-DIRECT
function set_one_time_redirect_cookie() {
    
    if (isset($_COOKIE['redirect_cookie'])) {
        return; // Redirect already occurred
    }

    $root_domain = '.example.com';  
    setcookie('redirect_cookie', 'true', time() +3600, '/', $root_domain, false, true );


    if ( $countryCode == 'CA' ) {

        wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/canada' , 302 );
        exit;

    } else {
        // Do nothing
    }

}
add_action('template_redirect', 'set_one_time_redirect_cookie');
?>
```

Everything functions smoothly while I'm logged into WordPress. However, when I'm logged out, the cookie fails to load unless I utilise either 'init' or 'wp' instead of 'template_redirect'. The problem with this workaround is that 'wp-redirect' doesn't function unless 'template_redirect' is used. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have it working now. It turned out to be my cache plugin 'WP-Rocket'. It was interfering with the cookie delivery. I was able to download a 'mandatory cookies' fix from their website: https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/1313-create-different-cache-files-with-dynamic-and-mandatory-cookies